# Template class friendship with constraints

Tags: c++, class, templates, c++20

I tried the following, but it does not compile:

```cpp
template<class LabelType>
    requires requires { typename LabelType::LetterType; }
class MonoidalFSA
{
    template<class T>
    friend class MonoidalFSA;
};
```

```
error: redeclaration of ‘template<class LabelType>  requires requires{typename LabelType::LetterType;} class MonoidalFSA’ with different constraints
```

Tried adding the constraint to the friend declaration as well, but I still get the same error.

```cpp
template<class LabelType>
    requires requires { typename LabelType::LetterType; }
class MonoidalFSA
{
    template<class T>
        requires requires { typename T::LetterType; }
    friend class MonoidalFSA;
};
```

Comment: Try `template<typename> friend class MonoidalFSA;`

Comment: @NathanOliver Same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second snippet is correct, but it looks like gcc doesn't accept it because it thinks the two requires expressions aren't equivalent.

If you wrap it up in a concept it is accepted:

```cpp
template<typename LabelType>
concept HasLetterType = requires { typename LabelType::LetterType; };

template<class LabelType> requires HasLetterType<LabelType>
class MonoidalFSA
{
    template<class T> requires HasLetterType<T>
    friend class MonoidalFSA;
};

// Or simply
template<HasLetterType LabelType>
class MonoidalFSA
{
    template<HasLetterType>
    friend class MonoidalFSA;
};
```